# Three related things

Tags: connections-puzzle, tribond

These three are related somehow, what is the connection?

- Peter
- Pat
- Pantoufle

The relationship is *not* based on the presence, or position, of their letters
(for example, they all start with the letter P).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it:

> They are all rabbits

Peter:

> Peter Rabbit, from Beatrix Potter

Pat:

> Pat the Bunny (thanks HDE226868)

Pantoufle:

> A rabbit named Pantoufle, from a novel/movie called Chocolat

Comment: It is indeed rabbit, but your pat is not the reason I used - the link is stronger - should be easy to work out now....

Comment: @JonathanAllan Hm. Is it [Pat the Bunny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pat_the_Bunny)?

Comment: @HDE226868 - yep, they are all fictional rabbits!

Comment: Thought of that, though as I remember it from my baby brother's babyhood, the you had to "pat" the furry bunny - it wasn't actually named Pat. Sorry to nitpick.

Answer (score 6):

All three can be connected by the word

> slip(per).

"Peter" could be a reference to

> [Peter Slipper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Slipper), an Australian politician.

"Pat" can mean

> a [pat of butter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pat), which is quite slippery.

"Pantoufle" is simple:

> [*Pantoufle* is French for "slipper".](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pantoufle)

Comment: I'm afraid not, the connection is stronger than the link you give for pat. +1 though.